# vim-airline - hide filetype in statusbar

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I would like to know how to hide the filetype in the statusbar in vim. For example when I open a .tex-File vim is showing me it is a "tex" file. I don't want this.

My statusline looks like this:

```
NORMAL>SPELL>git master> "filename"...< "filetype"< "encoding"<...
```

and I would like to remove the "filetype" part

for example:

```
NORMAL>SPELL>git master> main.tex ...< tex < utf-8[unix] <...
```

I also would like to know how to remove the "<" that would stay after removing the filetype (have several triangles left where I removed stuff like trailing and so on because I have no clue what the attribute names are which i have to set 0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out how to do it, earlier this day I didn't get the help part of vim-airline to do this the solution is:

```
" remove the filetype part
let g:airline_section_x=''
" remove separators for empty sections
let g:airline_skip_empty_sections = 1
```

Comment: can you provide a screenshot with the seperator you got still left?

Comment: I restarted all my tmux sessions and the outer left seperator in the tabbar on top of vim disappeared as it should be. Will edit my answer.